# dataimport API for solr

Tags: solr

I am using `pysolr` to access solr's client API. However, I could not find how to call `solr`'s data import. Regardless of this python library, does anyone know how to automate the process of data import with `solr`'s DIH?
Both for full import and delta import.

Answer (score 1):

If language is not a constraint , or even if you know how to make a Http GET and POST calls in Python , just after you create and define your entity , you can make rest calls like this http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import for Delta import or if you want to full-import replace it with full import . Regarding automation , if you have scheduling libraries in Python . You can easily automate the import using above url via scheduling . Or if you just want to do it after a certain period daily, just define a cronjob if you have Linux . It shall do it for you .

Comment: you are missing the collection name, between 'solr' and 'dataimport'.

Answer (score 0):

Using the API REST directly, for a full-import on 'mycollection' use a call like this:

```
curl -i "https://solr-server:8983/solr/mycollection/dataimport?command=full-import"
```

For a delta import, change 'full-import' to 'delta-import'.

Sadly, this call is not documented on the "Solr Ref Guide" to my knowledge.

Comment: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html